# Angular: Movable Dialog title as Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I figured out how to [move a dialog](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-78ofcc?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html). Its more or less a

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane" cdkDragHandle >{{data.header}}</h1>
```

This means that I have to add

```
mat-dialog-title cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane" cdkDragHandle
```

in each dialog. Since I'm lazy I don't want to add the same code all over my code. Therefore I thought to encapsulate those 4 directives (attributes?) into one single - e.g. `moveable-dialog-title`. I searched for the directives but found only answers function calls.

The addtional question is about styling. I can style the header in the css with `[mat-dialog-title] {..` When I have an encapsulated directive is styling per directive as well possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no "native" Angular to combine directives like that. You'd have to code a preprocessor yourself by introducing additional syntax to the templates.

Comment: why don't create a component `dialog-header` and put your code in its HTML and use that component instead

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @jitender was great. Therefore I created a component with simply

```
  <h1 mat-dialog-title cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane" cdkDragHandle >
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </h1>
```

And than just replacing in the required HTML code

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane" cdkDragHandle >{{data.header}}</h1>
```

with

```
<app-moveable-dialog-header>{{data.header}}</app-moveable-dialog-header>
```